# How to change colour of whole console in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is that i want to change color of whole console in python like you would do in cmd using color command:
i found many modules like rich,colourama,coloured to change the background but they only change the background color of text we print.i want to change background color of the whole console.Also i want the way to be OS independent and without using os.system and subprocess. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent of the Windows color command that works cross platform. On systems that use ANSI control codes (Linux, MacOS, and Windows Terminal) you can set a background color that will be used for all following text until it is changed or reset.

For instance, the following write the control codes for red background, but it won't set the entire terminal window red, nor will it have any effect on text that has already been printed.

```
print("\x1b[41mHello")
```

There is a caveat that many terminals may be themed, and you can set any background color you wish -- but you wouldn't be able to do that for theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the operating system you are running on and then run the os-specific command.

```py
import platform

my_os = platform.system() # will give 'Linux' if you are running linux

if my_os == 'Linux':
    os.system('setterm -background blue -foreground white -store')
elif my_os == 'Windows':
    os.system('color 1f')
```

One thing is that since you used a system call to change the color, the original color would not be restored on exit.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer but the question i asked was without using os.system or subprocess module(i.e i mean without using system commands such as setterm or color).BTW thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Windows specific way of doing it,

```py
import os
os.system("COLOR AA") # change color to AA
print("Something to print") # print something with new color and background
os.system("pause") # pause to see the effects
```

This would work if you open your .py file inside a cmd

Comment: Sorry i didnt explain my question well.i want a os independant python way of doing this

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll leave this as an example of how to change it based on Windows then in case someone wonders